# Create program Random

Tags: c

i want to randomize this program that recreates a quiz

I tried to add the rand function but I don't know how to proceed

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int domanda, punti=0;

    puts("Quiz sul Riscaldamento Globale\n Otterrai 1 punto per ogni risposta esatta e 0 per ogni risposta sbagliata o non valida\n");

    puts("D1) Secondo il tredicesimo Obiettivo di Sviluppo Sostenibile, la minaccia piu' grande allo sviluppo e'/sono:\n");

    puts("[1] I cambiamenti climatici\n"
           "[2] L'inquinamento \n"
           "[3] Lo scioglimento della calotta glaciale polare \n"
           "[4] La crescita demografica\n");

    scanf("%d", &domanda);

    if(domanda == 1){
        puts("risposta corretta\n");
        punti = punti + 1;
    }else{
        puts("risposta sbagliata\n");
        punti= punti + 0;
    }

    puts("D2) Il tempo e il clima sono la stessa cosa.");
    puts("[1] Vero \n"
           "[2] Falso \n");

    scanf("%d", &domanda);

    if(domanda == 2){
        printf("risposta corretta\n");
        punti =punti + 1;
    }else{
        printf("risposta sbagliata\n");
        punti= punti + 0;
    }

    printf("hai fatto un punteggio di %d su 2", punti);

}
```

to work it works but I don't understand how to add the random if anyone knows how to do it help me thanks.

Comment: What do you want to randomize? The order of asking the questions? Or the order of choices given to the user?

Comment: The order of the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `rand()` function is available in C standard library: [man 3 rand](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand). If you want to explore random number generation, check [random.org](https://www.random.org/).

As is, your program is not designed to support randomness: Questions and answers are hard-coded. A first step to make it randomizable would be to store them into a variable. For instance (with correct answer always at first position, end of questions identified with `NULL`, end of answers of a question identified with `NULL`, maximum of nine answers per question):

```
struct {
   char * question;
   char * answers[10];
} qa[] = {
   {
      "Secondo il tredicesimo Obiettivo di Sviluppo Sostenibile, la minaccia piu",
      {
         "I cambiamenti climatici",
         "L'inquinamento",
         "Lo scioglimento della calotta glaciale polare",
         "La crescita demografica",
         NULL,
      }
   },
   {
      "Il tempo e il clima sono la stessa cosa.",
      {
         "Falso",
         "Vero",
         NULL,
      }
   },
   { NULL, NULL }
};
```

A program using this variable would then count the number of questions, take one randomly, then display the answers randomly and remember what is the display index of the correct one.